# Is there a way to access datastores from 2 separate projects in the same script?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a python script that needs to access 2 different datastores. I've only been able to have credentials up for one project or the other, not both at once. Is there work around for this?

I'm writing in python and my computer is running Windows 10. I have .json files with service account keys that I use for my credentials, setting an environment variable for them. When I have both credential files listed in the environment variable, any query I try to create is None. When I only have one credential file listed in the environment variable, one query will work while the other will give me a 403 error.

Comment: You'll have to change your setup to leverage multiple client instances. You won't be able to rely on Environment Variables, you have to do this manually.

Comment: @DimuDesigns Can you explain how to do this? I've only worked with google cloud for a couple of months at my internship this summer.